# Adding Watermark to Screenshots in Flutter App on Android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, flutter, image-processing, screenshot

**Question:**
I am working on a Flutter app and I need to implement a feature where a watermark is automatically added to screenshots taken by the user from within my app. This functionality should work on both Android and iOS devices. While I understand how to handle screenshots within the app using packages like `screenshot`, my requirement is to add a watermark specifically to screenshots taken using the default operating system functionality (e.g., power button + volume down on Android, or power button + home button on iOS).

Is there a way to intercept these system-level screenshot events and programmatically add a watermark to the resulting images before they are saved to the device's gallery? I would prefer a solution that doesn't involve ejecting from Flutter and writing platform-specific code in Java/Kotlin for Android or Objective-C/Swift for iOS.

**Details:**
I have explored various Flutter packages for handling screenshots within the app, but they do not cover the scenario where the user takes a screenshot using the default system shortcuts. I want to add a watermark to these screenshots automatically.

I am looking for a solution that works seamlessly on both Android and iOS, ensuring that the watermark is added reliably without requiring the user to perform any additional steps. Any guidance, code snippets, or relevant packages would be greatly appreciated.

**Update:**
I have investigated platform channels for Flutter, but I am unsure how to intercept system-level screenshot events and modify the resulting images. If there is a way to achieve this functionality without ejecting from Flutter, it would be ideal for my project. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: There is no way to add a watermark to the screenshot on iOS unless the watermark is already on the screen before the user triggers the screenshot

Comment: The same is true on Android.  You can _prevent_ screenshots, but not intercept/modify them.  Your only option would be to have the watermark always visible.